# Freeing up disk space on azure web apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've recently been on a support ticket with Azure, and they've recommended turning on [Local caching](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-local-cache/) to eliminate occasional outage blips.

The problem with that, is that you need to watch your disk space, since >1Gig is not allowed. And if you deploy from git, like I do, that's an issue because the whole repository is checked out, then built locally, and then kudu-synced.

I've looked at trimming my repo down, but that's only going to yield small savings. What I'd like to do is to remove my `repository` folder once the deployment has complete. Is that a sensible idea, or are there other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an upcoming change to the Local Caching behavior that will make it skip the repository folder (since it's not needed at runtime). This should be in the next couple of weeks.

Once that change is out, this issue should automatically go away for you.

Answer (score 1):

the repository folder only container a copy of your repo. it is ok to remove it if you want to safe some space. it will be re-create when there is a new deployment.

There is one side effect when you delete your repository folder, your next deployment will take longer time since it will need to sync your entire repository.

Other than repository folder, you can cleanup files that under D:\home\LogFiles as well, to safe you some more spaces

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use build sequence using Visual Studio Team Services - there, [you can do anything you want and include operations into the build pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/azure/aspnet4) (build trigger => delete the folder).